# Statistical test for relationships when many samples are unknown

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I'm fairly new to statistics - I'm sure this is a basic question but my google searching is failing me. Happy to just be pointed to other reading.

I have 3 datasets of varying sizes (N1 ~ 200,000, N2 ~ 80,000, N3 ~ 400). In each dataset, for each sample (row in the dataframe, I'm not even sure what the right vocabulary is here) I have 5 different data points (the columns). Each data point started life as a first name, and the thing I'm interested in is gender. I used [genderize.io](http://genderize.io) to test names, and they return a gender, a probability and a sample size (their dataset is based on census data, social media profiles etc).

I modified the gender variables to all be `P-female` (so `(F, 0.95, 300)` becomes `(0.95, 300)` and `(M, 0.9, 50)` becomes `(0.1, 50)`. But the gender may also be unknown, which means there were no samples of that name in the database.

There are a couple of different tests I want to do to look for differences. The null hypothesis in all cases is that there's no difference.

I want to test:

1. whether there's a difference between columns within a single dataset (so check whether there's a difference in `P-female` between column 1 and column 2, or column 2 and column 3 etc within a single dataset).
2. whether there's a difference between datasets for each column (is `column1` in `Set1` different from `column1` in `Set2`?).
3. If there's a difference between data sets in the difference between columns within the datasets. Eg, if the difference between `column1` and `column2` in `Set1` is larger or smaller than the difference between `column1` and `column2` in `Set2`.

A major consideration is that the "unknown" genders are ~50% of each set of samples.

I've no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I can provide additional information.

EDIT: More info about dataset -

I'm looking at authorship in scientific publications. I pulled data from Pubmed and I parsed the author lists and put them into 5 bins. `First_Author`, `Last_Author`, `Second_Author`, `Penultimate_Author`, `Other_authors`. My script basically fills out the positions in that order, so if there are only 3 authors, that paper gets a name in `First_Author`, `Second_Author` and `Last_Author`. If there are 20 authors, each of the named positions gets one name, and the `Other_Authors` gets an array of 16 names.

EDIT2:

Not sure if this is relevant, but after reading some other posts here, I thought it might be important. `DataSet2` should be a subset of `DataSet1` and `DataSet3` should be a subset of `DataSet2`. I say "should be" because the search terms I used should have this behavior, but I haven't actually checked. It would be possible for me to check if this information is important.

Comment: What are the columns? I gather one column is the listed first name & another column is the identified gender, but what are the other three?

Comment: No, each column is filled with tuples `(P(f), n)`. The 5 columns are positions in an author list (I'm looking at scientific publications, so I have a column for first author, a column for last author etc)

Comment: You should say more about your data and your study. What happens when an author list isn't 5 people, eg?

Comment: @gung sure - just added more info to the body. Let me know if there's more I should add.